# Smooth scroll to an element after switching state in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, state, smooth-scrolling

I am developing in Angular using a node package for smooth scrolling. I have a navbar on all my pages (as a directive) and if someone is on my history state `/history` and clicks on a link in the navbar to go to a specific section on the homepage `/`, I want the site to switch states to the homepage state and then to scroll automatically to the section that the user clicked on in the navbar.

Right now I'm doing

```
    scope.goToSection = function (val, state) {
        $state.go(state)
        setTimeout(function() {smoothScroll(document.querySelector(val))}, 100);
    }
```

which is working but I am not sure if this is the most natural way to get this functionality.

I tried `$state.go(state).then(smoothScroll(document.querySelector(val)));` but the page would not scroll after switching states. Is there a better or more natural way to get this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with custom functions used to switch states instead of ui-sref is that you lose for example the posibility to click with the mouse wheel to open in the new tab etc.

Solution to this would be to check $stateChangeSuccess event and scroll based on the data passed to the new state.

```
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(e, toState, toParams) {
        // do the scrolling

    });
```